# How do you run a 5v MCU circuit on a 12v car battery?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage-regulator, control

My Archery club has asked me to design and build a Traffic Light system for shooting, but they want it to run on a 12v car battery as this is what our previous system ran on.

I'm going to make the system using the pic18f4550 as the controller, so it can have an automatic mode as well as a manual mode, but this must run at no more then 5.5v. So I was going to use this 5v regulator circuit:http://thedasdet.deviantart.com/art/5v-Regulator-358912063

I'm worried that the 12v car battery will supply to much current and blow the regulator. If so  what can I do to prevent this?

Comment: I've downvoted based on the fact that this question has been asked so many times before, and the answer is all the same. A cursory search would have found them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Current is always *drawn*, not *supplied*: that is, connecting something that can supply a lot of current does not mean that it will.

The standard 5V linear regulator will work fine, but it will dissipate power as heat, proportional to the amount of current drawn by the PIC. I'd suggest something based around a "switchmode" power supply, or cannibalising a car USB power converter (cheap and widely available).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/181005107235

I bought a few of these for powering my Raspberry Pi.  Easy and cheap.  Being switched-mode, there's very little wasted energy as heat, and the adjustable output means it'll suit whatever projects you take on in the future (say with a 3.3V chip instead).

Comment: what the heck was this item..... Obviously it has sold or been removed....

Comment: It was probably a LM2956 based buck converter, (avaialvle on alieexpress for less than a buck each if you buy 10 an can wait for snail mail)

Comment: I agree. The current is drawn. Like those phone power adaptors the plug in a cigarette lighter in a motor vehicle. Those phones don't run on 12V and they don't burn up doing this. Best analogy I can come up with so anyone reading this page will understand.

Comment: What have we learned so far?

    Voltage is potential, but electricity needs to flow to do anything useful.
    Electricity needs a path to flow through, which must be an electrical conductor such as copper wire.
    Electricity will flow from a higher voltage to a lower voltage.
    DC voltage sources always have two sides, called positive and negative, with the positive side a higher voltage than the negative side.
https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/what-is-a-circuit

Answer (score -1):

Just make sure the total current you plan to draw (from the micro as well as the lights (if they are running on the same 5V)) is less than the maximum rated current of the voltage regulator.